# Regex Speed Improvement C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am processing few text files using regex. The lines in the text file can be any of the few pre selected patterns (upto 8 patterns). Below are the sample

```
 static Regex regExCase1= new Regex(@"^\s+Result\s(\S+)\s\S+\,\s(\S+)\s\S\sLocation\sID\s(\S+)",,RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
 static Regex regExCase2= new Regex(@"^\s+Result\s(\S+)\s\S+,\s+\S\sLocation\sAt\s\S(\d)",,RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

The regex is quite optimised. It was originally written with VB.NET and converted into C#. I believe lots of time is lost in checking each pattern twice, once with IsMatch() and other time with Matches().  I am thinking of updating the code to consider the pattern check only once and wondering if there is an alternative way to do this. Can some one suggest me if it is worth updating the code. As the change requires change in the logic, the feedback would be very useful.

```
if (regExCase1.IsMatch(TextLine))
{
      matches = regExCase1.Matches(TextLine);
      Param1 = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
      Param2= matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
      Param3= matches[0].Groups[3].Value;
      statusCase1= true;  //bool
 }
 else if (regExCase2.IsMatch(TextLine))
 {
      matches = regExCase2.Matches(TextLine);
      Param1 = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
      Param2= matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
      Param3= matches[0].Groups[3].Value;
      statusCase2= true;  //bool
} 
elseif(/*....*/)
{
   /*...*/
}
```

Comment: For `regExCase2` there is no 3rd group so you can omit this `Param3= matches[0].Groups[3].Value;`

Comment: So all the 8 patterns have a different number of capturing groups?

Comment: Yes. The number of capturing groups are different. You are right about the previous comment. It was a typo from my side. Well spotted. My original code has only 2 groups for it.

Comment: You can also Compile the Regex. The performance difference is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to do first `IsMatch`, you can use directly `Matches` and avoid the double processing:

```
var matches = regExCase1.Matches(TextLine);

if(matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
{
    //Process the results
}
else
{
    matches = regExCase2.Matches(TextLine);
    if(matches != null && matches.Count > 0)
    {
        //Process the results
    }
    else
    {
        //Other cases
    }
}
```

Also, your code checks only the first result on the `MatchCollection`, if there can be only one result per check then use `Match` instead of `Matches`.